# Cannot open simulator in vs code

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Hey I'm new at flutter can some one help me..?
I want to run flutter on UBUNTU 20.04 with Visual Studio Code
but when I run `open -a simulator`
it throws an error

```
Command 'open' not found, did you mean:

  command 'wopen' from deb gworkspace.app (0.9.4-2)
  command 'pen' from deb pen (0.34.1-1build1)
  command 'gopen' from deb gnustep-gui-runtime (0.27.0-5build2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

and I dont have Android Studio . some one help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install android studio
- From ADV manager in android studio, create a simulator.
- After creation of a device, you can either run it from VScode without launching android studio, it'll be visible in `device` when you run your code. Or if you want to work with Android Studio, which I doubt you would want to do, it'll run from there out of the box also.
- `open -a simulator` doesn't run on ubuntu, as the error says, `open` isn't defined.
- On a MacOS, you can do that for an iOS emulator device, but it's Ubuntu, so no iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Android studio to run the Android emulator or you can try to run it on a physical device

Comment: yes i tried to run with physical device also.. with USB debugging still I cant.. but finally i run the simulator on chrome with  flutter run -d chrome